# Scala implicit conversions order

Tags: scala

I have two objects with similar method ~(...). I also defined implicit conversions which should convert pair (String, A) to either DemoObject or WopWopWop

```
class DemoObject[A](t: (String, A)) {
  def ~(t: (String, A)) = "demo"
}

class WopWopWop[A](t: (String, A)) {
  def ~(t: AnyVal) = "wop wop wop"
}

object ImplicitDemoConversions {
  implicit def pair2DemoObject[A](t: (String, A)) = new DemoObject(t)
}

object ImplicitWopWopWopConversions {
  implicit def pair2WopWopWop[A](t: (String, A)) = new WopWopWop(t)
}
```

However, having something like

```
import ImplicitDemoConversions._
object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import ImplicitWopWopWopConversions._
    val pair = ("LolTest" -> "A") ~ ("whoa" -> "wop wop wop")

    println(pair) 
  }
}
```

will print answer **demo** instead of expected **wop wop wop**. Looks like scala compiler ignores second import of ImplicitWopWopWopConversions._

Question is why do I think that pair **(String, String)** should be converted to *WopWopWop* and how do I get WopWopWop object instead of DemoObject?

You can find real example here https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/121

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the import with an alias.

```
import ImplicitDemoConversions.{pair2DemoObject => i}
object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import ImplicitWopWopWopConversions.{pair2WopWopWop => i}
    val pair = ("LolTest" -> "A") ~ ("whoa" -> "wop wop wop")

    println(pair) 
  }
}
```

**Edit**

The reason that your tuple is being converted to a `DemoObject` instead of a `WopWopWop` is because `DemoObject`'s `~` method argument type is more specific than `WopWopWop`'s.

It's just like this example:

```
object A {
    def m(x: AnyVal) { println(x) }
    def m(x: (Int, String)) { println(x) }

    // This will call the first method, because the second method can't be
    // applied to an Int
    a(1)
    // Either method could be applied to a (Int, String), but the second 
    // method will be chosen, because it's argument type is more specific.
    a((1 -> "hello"))
}
```

Comment: So is there any way to tell scala explicitly which conversion to use? In my case unfortunately I cannot change any code in libraries I'm using

Comment: @VladislavMiller The only way I could think of was to hide the higher precedence import with an alias (first example). If you need to limit the scope of the hiding import, you could try wrapping it, and the code that uses it in a closure.